# How to use Feed importer to import content type in which one of the field is node reference field type?

Tags: feeds, nodes

I have a content type, in which one field has multiple values and they are referred from another content type. How can I upload this content type from a .csv file with the help of feeds importer?

Answer (score 0):

I have used feeds tamper. Multiple values are comma separated in the file that I intended to upload. I have added explode plugin and , delimeter in the feed importer page (tamper).